# Make carousel stop on first and last slide (ng-swipe)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I'm working in an AngularJS application version 1.5.9 and I'm working on building out a carousel.

I have everything working besides the fact that I need the carousel to stop on the first and last slide on my `ng-swipe-left` and `ng-swipe-right`.

```html
<div class='ut-position-relative'>
    <div class='mo-karousel'
       ng-swipe-left='ctrl.updateSlidePosition(ctrl.positionMoveToSlide)'
       ng-swipe-right='ctrl.updateSlidePosition(ctrl.positionMoveToSlide)'>
      <atom-carousel-arrow class='ut-position-absolute-c-v-l ut-bring-up-2 ut-hide-u-main'
        is-left='true'
        ng-click='ctrl.updateSlidePosition(ctrl.constantDirectionNext)'>
      </atom-carousel-arrow>
      <div class='st-container st-container--nowrap ut-overflow-hidden-x'
           ng-transclude=''>
      </div>
      <div class='ut-position-absolute-c-h-b ut-bring-neutral ut-fill-width ut-align-text-c'>
          <div class='is-rounded-edges ut-margin-r-xxsm ut-display-inline-block ut-padding-a-xxxsm'
               ng-class="{'mo-color-bg-dark-grey': 1 === slide.position,
                          'mo-color-bg-light-grey': 1 !== slide.position}"
               ng-click='ctrl.positionMoveToSlide($index)'
               ng-repeat='slide in ctrl.slides track by $index'>
          </div>
      </div>
      <atom-carousel-arrow class='ut-position-absolute-c-v-r ut-bring-up-2 ut-hide-u-main' 
          ng-click='ctrl.updateSlidePosition(ctrl.constantDirectionPrev)'>
      </atom-carousel-arrow>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
(function () {
  this.positionRotate = function (n) {
    if (self.nextOrPrev === self.constantDirectionNext) {
      n--;
    } else {
      n++;
    }
    if (n > self.slides.length) {
      n = 1;
    } else if (n < 1) {
      n = self.slides.length;
    }
    return n;
  };

  this.updateSlidePosition = function (nextOrPrev) {
    if (self.isSlidesReady) {
      self.nextOrPrev = nextOrPrev;
      _.each(self.slides, function (slide) {
        return slide.position = self.positionRotate(slide.position);
      });
    }
    return this;
  };

}).call(this);
```

---

Yeah they both work they're just not working as expected.I have a click event on the dots on the carousel which is calling `ctrl.positionMoveToSlide($index)` and in my controller I'm doing

```
this.positionMoveToSlide = function(index) {
    var results;
    if (self.isSlidesReady) { 
        results = [];
        while (!(self.slides[index].position < 2)) {
            results.push(_.each(self.slides, function(slide) {
                 return slide.position = self.positionRotate(slide.position);
            })
          );
        }
        return results;
    }
};
```

Thats working perfectly because I'm able to access the `$index`

Comment: Do the `ng-swipe-left` and `ng-swipe-right` directives work? It looks like they both invoke the same function.

Comment: Yeah they both work they're just not working as expected.I have a click event on the dots on the carousel which is calling `ctrl.positionMoveToSlide($index)` and in my controller I'm doing 
```
this.positionMoveToSlide = function(index) {
        var results;
        if (self.isSlidesReady) {
          results = [];
          while (!(self.slides[index].position < 2)) {
            results.push(_.each(self.slides, function(slide) {
              return slide.position = self.positionRotate(slide.position);
            }));
          }
          return results;
        }
      };```

Comment: Thats working perfectly because I'm able to access the $index

Answer (score 0):

I would rotate the slides differently:

```
function mapRotate(arr, position) = > (
    arr.map( (_,i) => arr[(position+i) % arr.length] )
);
```

This makes a new array that is rotated from the original by the value of the `position` argument. This avoids using a `while` loop.

Instead of mutating the original array of slides, create a new array for viewing based on the desired position.

```
this.position = 0;
this.slidesToView = mapRotate(this.slides, this.position);

this.slideToN = n => {
    if (n<0 || n>= this.position.length) return;
    this.position = n;
    this.slidesToView = mapRotate(this.slides, this.position);
};

this.slideLeft = () => {
    if (this.position == 0) return;
    this.position--;
    this.slideToN(this.position);
};     

this.slideRight = () => {
    if (this.position == this.slides.length-1) return;
    this.position++;
    this.slideToN(this.position);
};
```